# display default image if file does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to display a default image when the given image is not found.  As my code is now, it always shows the default image.  Can I not use `Url.Content` in `File.Exists()`?

Here is my code:

```
@if (File.Exists(Url.Content("~/Content/img/" + item.name + ".jpg")))
{
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/" + item.name + ".jpg")" alt="@item.longname" />
}
else
{
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/default.png")" alt="@item.longname" />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) like:

```
File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/" + item.name + ".jpg"))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest to move this code into a Controller or external class to make it more readable.

Use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the real file name of the url.

That file path can be checked with `File.Exists`.